# is javascript multithreading possible with IFRAMEs

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I'm currently playing with the idea of using IFRAMEs to implement a very simple multithreading engine.  However my initial results are showing me that running in threads is slower than just running in a single thread.

My test is:

**Single Thread**

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) { /* Do costly processor operations */ }
debug('Took: ' + new Date().getTime() - start);
```

**Multiple Threads**

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
// In thread 1
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { /* Do costly processor operations */ }
// In thread 2
for (var i = 100; i < 200; i++) { /* Do costly processor operations */ }
// In thread 3
for (var i = 200; i < 300; i++) { /* Do costly processor operations */ }
// In a callback in the original FRAME (thread)
debug('Took: ' + new Date().getTime() - start);
```

So as can be seen, I'm just splitting the work load amongst IFRAMEs (Note code above is only to give a better picture of what I am doing, it is not working code).

So I'm thinking that even using FRAMEs FireFox still has only one JS engine?  Is this assumption correct? (rendering my research stupid), Are other browsers different?

Doing a quick googles I got this article: http://codediaries.blogspot.com/2009/12/real-javascript-multithreading-using.html

However the performance improvements achieved here are more than likely just doing parallel http requests rather than processing power.

Thanks for your insights.

Guido

Comment: How about you add some zeroes to the loop counter? Make it 10000, 20000 and 30000 respectively and see what happens.

Comment: chakrit: My real tests are using 1000s of iterations, the example above is small just for simplicity.

Comment: One thing to make sure you also take into account is JavaScript timer resolution, which is often 15ms: http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/

Comment: Even if distributing computation to multiple iframes would work as real multi-threading, wouldn't the overhead necessary to run five such engines render naught any possible gain in performance?

Comment: What is it you're doing that even requires multithreading?

Comment: Pekka, the article linked in the question shows a gain in performance from multiple threads (although it looks like gatapia was having trouble reproducing the results).

Breton, here are some interesting applications of JS workers: http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [HTML5 Web Workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/) Standard to see what JavaScript threading should look like. This is implemented in Firefox 3.5, Safari 4, and Chrome 3, but not IE. If you're willing to require a plugin for IE users and older browsers, check out [Google Gears WorkerPool](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_workerpool.html).

Comment: It's available today, in 3 of the 4 most popular browsers (firefox, safari, chrome)

Comment: +1 for introducing me to Web Workers! This is going to save me some serious time :) thx Annie

Answer (score 0):

No, Javascript generally does not support multi-threading.  Most interpreters do not have any multi-threading capabilities built-in (just like PHP), probably for portability reasons.

However, since the [Rhino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_(JavaScript_engine)) engine is written entirely in Java, you [may be able to tap into the Thread class](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/ScriptingJava.html), but this would only be feasible if you are doing server-side Javascript.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the setTimeout approaches, however that just queues work in the single thread so no good.  I was just hoping that iframes would use their own interpreter (engine).

Comment: No, it does not work that way.  It is still just one browser instance.  You would have to launch a new window, and I am not even sure if that would work either.

Comment: Worth a try though.  Launch a few windows, make them small as possible and move them to the corner.  Use `opener` to access the underlying collection.  Im on an iPhone otherwise I'd do it LOL.  Watching the Husker game.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of a window.open approach, the only problem with this is that you would have all these windows popping up when you needed a thread (that is if it works).  You can hide iframes but I don;t think you can hide windows (they would at least appear on your task bar or as empty tabs).

Comment: Regardless, you are not going to get away with it unless you "trick the system".  What's interesting is that the Ruby language actually has multi-threading capabilities built into its interpreter (as opposed to OS wrappers), so you would think it is conceivable with Javascript, but no interpreters that I know of support it at this point.

Comment: If you only care about Firefox, you may be able to tap into the Java Thread class, since the Rhino interpreter is written in Java:  http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/ScriptingJava.html

Comment: Conversely, if you're looking to make this work on any browser, you should re-run your test on Google Chrome since its multi-process architecture may mean that JavaScript in different frames runs in different processes.

Comment: Josh: Firefox uses Spidermonkey, not Rhino.

Comment: @Ken True (and soon to be called TraceMonkey), but they are essentially brother and sister.

Comment: @Ken, @Josh, it's true firefox uses spidermonkey, not rhino, but spidermonkey has access to liveconnect, which provides a rhino-like bridge to java from javascript in a browser. I do not believe it's possible though still, since threading in JAVA requires the ability to subclass/implement a runnable thread class interface, which can only be done from javascript in rhino. However, you could run rhino in a java applet, and multithread javascripts inside the applet.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided on a browser dependant solution.  Basically I will use [Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers) if available, then [Gears](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_workerpool.html) if available. Finally just single threaded.

Thanks all

Guido

Comment: You should probably just select Annie's answer as "accepted" then (click the large checkmark to the right of her answer, under the voting buttons). That will tell people that her answer pretty much meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**setTimeout** call might be a good solution in some circumstances.

It depends what you call a thread. No, this isn't going to spread any load out to other cores, but it IS multithreading in that the thread for the process gets given up to another process in the code. Split your heavy cycles into chunks and it you will let the rendering engine and other events get a look in.

Answer (score -1):

You could try wrapping your operations in a setTimeout call.